# Wpf Width binding to property with star

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, width

Can you bind the width of a property to the value of an object times star, for example,

(Width="{Binding SizeInt*}") in xaml?

In the code behind you can do this:

```
rect.Width = new GridLength(item.SizeInt, GridUnitType.Star);
```

I want to be able to have the same effect in xaml like so...

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Red" Width="{Binding SizeInt*}"/>
```

Is there a way to do this using xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind to a `GridLength` souce property:

```
public GridLength SizeInt => new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

You can replace `1` with any value you want, including the value of another field.